# transfer data from excel to mnesia in erlang

Tags: erlang

I have data that are stored in an Excel file

This file contains two columns: Name and Surname

and contains several lines

my goal is to Register this data in my database mnesia (in the person table that contains two attributes: Name and Surname)

is it possible to save data from excel file to mnesia database

if it is not possible to import data from excel file to mnesia can we convert the source file ( excel file) to .sql or to .txt and after that import this file to mnesia

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way, i think, is to export/save excel data to csv file, and then parse it from erlang with code like this.

```
{ok, Data} = file:read_file("test.csv"),
ParsedData = lists:map(
    fun(Str) -> string:tokens(Str, ",") end,
    string:tokens(binary_to_list(Data), "\n")
),
lists:foreach(fun([K,V]) -> mnesia:write(K, V) end, ParsedData).
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the Excel file as `.csv` file. Then you can use the `CSV Parser` i provided here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10810660/431620 . It is extremely simple and straight forward to import data from Excel.

**EDIT**

---

And i forgot something, the CSV parser i provided above ensures that any file size can be parsed into any erlang application you want. This is done by scanning the file, rather than reading it all into memory at once. Beware of writing code which attempt to read a file at once, a big file will crash the vm.
We have used that program to import large csv dump files from other Database like SQL Server and Oracle into Mnesia.

Answer (score 0):

I create this file **csv.erl** :

```
%%% --- csv parser in Erlang. ------
%%% To help process large csv files without loading them into
%%% memory. Similar to the xml parsing technique of SAX

-module(csv).
-compile(export_all).

parse(FilePath,ForEachLine,Opaque)->
    case file:open(FilePath,[read]) of
        {_,S} ->
            start_parsing(S,ForEachLine,Opaque);
        Error -> Error
    end.

start_parsing(S,ForEachLine,Opaque)->
    Line = io:get_line(S,''),
    case Line of
        eof -> {ok,Opaque};
        "\n" -> start_parsing(S,ForEachLine,Opaque);
        "\r\n" -> start_parsing(S,ForEachLine,Opaque);
        _ -> 
            NewOpaque = ForEachLine(scanner(clean(clean(Line,10),13)),Opaque),
            start_parsing(S,ForEachLine,NewOpaque)
    end.

scan(InitString,Char,[Head|Buffer]) when Head == Char -> 
    {lists:reverse(InitString),Buffer};
scan(InitString,Char,[Head|Buffer]) when Head =/= Char ->
    scan([Head|InitString],Char,Buffer);
scan(X,_,Buffer) when Buffer == [] -> {done,lists:reverse(X)}.
scanner(Text)-> lists:reverse(traverse_text(Text,[])).

traverse_text(Text,Buff)->
    case scan("",$,,Text) of
        {done,SomeText}-> [SomeText|Buff];
        {Value,Rem}-> traverse_text(Rem,[Value|Buff])
    end.

clean(Text,Char)-> 
    string:strip(string:strip(Text,right,Char),left,Char).
```

and I create a function in order to extract data from csv file :

```
test()->

    ForEachLine = fun(Line,Buffer)-> io:format("Line: ~p~n",[Line]),Buffer end,

 InitialBuffer = [],

 csv:parse("/home/include/person.csv",ForEachLine,InitialBuffer).
```

and in the console of erlang it displys the correct result :

```
1> operation:test(). 
Line: ["50;97919861;5ab190537df;9898abb6e;efb65a0ad1;1",
       "35427;1",
       "3542;30-11-2012;testU2;testU6;undefined;m.;enabled;jjj;A999997;97979797;CIN;testU@gmail.com;b1088b51297846e;0;user;0;{{2012",
       "11","30}","{1","59",
       "26}};gggg;kkkk;ssss;standard;{2012","11",
       "30};hhhh;mmm;undefined;18;yyyy;nnnn;false;{{2012",
       "11","30}","{1","59","26}};1989;1;1"]
ok
```

Now my goals is to register this data in the mnesia database ( in the table person)

the table person has 49 attributes

so register this line

```
   Line: ["50;97919861;5ab190537df;9898abb6e;efb65a0ad1;1",
           "35427;1",
           "3542;30-11-2012;testU2;testU6;undefined;m.;enabled;jjj;A999997;97979797;CIN;testU@gmail.com;b1088b51297846e;0;user;0;{{2012",
           "11","30}","{1","59",
           "26}};gggg;kkkk;ssss;standard;{2012","11",
           "30};hhhh;mmm;undefined;18;yyyy;nnnn;false;{{2012",
           "11","30}","{1","59","26}};1989;1;1"]
```

in the table person which has this structure :

```
-record(person, {id, token, password, pin, key, salt, pin_salt, subscription_date, first_name, last_name, alias, gender, status,
                 taxid, formid, idcard, id_type, email, activation_code, email_confirmation, role,
                 trying, last_access, last_activity, last_activity_ip, last_activity_op_code, group, last_mod, last_login,
                 agent_code, agency_code, parent_id,pass_changes, pin_changes, is_merchant, created_at, birth_year, birth_month, birth_date}).
```